# what changes i need to do to make my code in newer node version?

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules

I have a js code which is working in node version 6. Now I want to upgrade the node version to 10 and trying to make sure that code should work in node 10. I have upgraded node modules using npm update. I am getting some node fiber errors. Attached the screenshot for your reference.

[image: This is the error message after upgrading to node 10 and node modules.]

**This is my package.json**

```
{
  "name": "DocumentConversion-schedular",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "this is the schedular for the compucom project",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node App",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "Vivek Kumar",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "async": "^2.2.0",
    "aws-sdk": "^2.32.0",
    "csvtojson": "^1.1.4",
    "extract-zip": "^1.6.0",
    "filecopy": "^3.0.1",
    "fs": "0.0.1-security",
    "fs-promise": "^2.0.1",
    "fs-readfile-promise": "latest",
    "html2json": "latest",
    "jsonfile": "latest",
    "mammoth": "latest",
    "mkdirp": "latest",
    "node-cron": "^1.1.3",
    "nodemailer": "^3.1.8",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "pdf-text": "latest",
    "pdf-to-text": "latest",
    "pdfreader": "latest",
    "properties-reader": "latest",
    "request": "^2.81.0",
    "stream": "0.0.2",
    "sync": "latest",
    "unzip": "^0.1.11",
    "winston": "^2.3.1",
    "xml-js": "latest",
    "xml-to-json": "latest"
  }
}
```

Comment: What's your npm version?

Comment: I am using nvm to change versions between 6 and 10. My npm in node 10 is 6.2.0

Comment: Delete everything in node_modules then do `npm install` again?

Comment: Mostly newer packages are built with latest node features may make the packages not work well with lower version of node, so maybe upgrading node version if deleting the `node_modules` may solve your problem